# C++ program not getting desired output

Tags: c++, loops, increment, decrement

Would you please help me on this one

i am running a simple c++ program and although i can get an output the way it is wriiten in book but when I modify it in a way which I think is logically correct then am not getting a correct answer. Beginner here.

Original Program (working):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // make a program that finds the total of ages in a random family whose size we dont know

    // we will ask for input from the user multiple times using a loop
    // if user enters -1 program termintaes

    int age;
    int total = 0 ;

    cout << "What is the age of the first person?"  << endl ;
    cin >> age;


        while(age != -1)
        {
                total  = total + age ;
            cout << "What is the age of the next person?"  << endl ;
            cin >> age;


        }

        cout << "The total age is " << total << endl ;

        return 0;



}
```

Modified one (not working dont know why)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // make a program that finds the total of ages in a random family whose size we dont know

    // we will ask for input from the user multiple times using a loop
    // if user enters -1 program termintaes

    int age;
    int total = 0 ;

    cout << "What is the age of the first person?"  << endl ;
    cin >> age;

      total  = total + age ;


        while(age != -1)
        {

            cout << "What is the age of the next person?"  << endl ;
            cin >> age;

                total  = total + age ;
        }

        cout << "The total age is " << total << endl ;

        return 0;



}
```

Comment: The second version does not handle -1 correctly in either case.

Comment: It's because you moved the test for age being negative. So you end up adding even negative age. -1 to be precise.

Comment: BTW: this is perfect example for running the program under debugger and see what variables contain after each step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code if you enter -1 for the first entry.

```
  cin >> age;

  total  = total + age ;
```

Then -1 will be added to total and while loop will be skipped.

```
    while(age != -1)
    {

        cout << "What is the age of the next person?"  << endl ;
        cin >> age;

            total  = total + age ;
    }
```

And same goes for the rest of the code. If you enter -1 inside loop, then it will be first added to total and then tested and loop quits.

So you should stick with your first version. 
As an exercise you might put total = total + 1 after the loop. Which will compensate for -1. But only as exercise.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying